# If {$b_n$} converges to b, then prove that {|$b_n$|} converges to |b|.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-value

Is my proof good or does it need more work?
Let $\epsilon$ > 0, we want N s.t. $\forall$ n $\geq$ N $\subset$ ||$b_n$| - |b|| < $\epsilon$. If |$b_n$| $\longrightarrow$ |b|, then $\exists$ N $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ s.t. |$b_n$ - b| < $\epsilon$ $\forall$ n $\geq$ N.
$\therefore$ {$b_n$} $\longrightarrow$ b and {|$b_n$|} $\longrightarrow$ |b|

Comment: Limits and continuous functions commute. $x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous.

Comment: @par That is obviously too advanced here.

Answer (score 5):

$ ||x| - |y||\leq|x - y| $ thus for that N we have $\forall$ n $\geq$ N
 |$|b_n| - |b||\leq |b_n - b| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

$|a-b| \ge ||a|-|b||$ for any $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Due to the level of OP, I think you need to expand your answer little more to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**An other way**

$x\mapsto |x|$ is continuous at $\ell$, and thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }|b_n|=|\lim_{n\to\infty }b_n|=|\ell|.$$